# JQuery Clone: Updated values not reflected on the cloned DOM

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem regarding to the values of the object that I cloned.
I cloned the div container and did some modification (fetching data from database to set the value for example) after that, clone the object. The cloned object persisted its selected value not the updated value.

Below is the sample code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/og2vu5a4/7/)

```
<div id="container">
<select id="ddl">
    <option selected>Value1</option>
    <option>Value2</option>
    <option>Value3</option>
    <option>Value4</option>
</select>

</div>
<div id="clonecontainer">
</div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var div = $('#container');
    var msg = $(div).find('#ddl');
    $(msg).val("Value3").prop('selected', 'selected');
    alert($(div).find('#ddl').val());

    var tr = $(div).clone(true, true);
    alert($(tr).find('#ddl').val());
    $(tr).appendTo("#clonecontainer");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` instead of `id` (for further operations) and set the current `value` to cloned element -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div = $('#container');
    var msg = $(div).find('.ddl');
    $(msg).val("Value3").prop('selected', 'selected');

    var tr = $(div).clone(true, true).find('select').val($(div).find('.ddl').val());
    $(tr).appendTo("#clonecontainer");

});
```

Comment: **[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/og2vu5a4/8/)**

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. This will only works if we only have 1 control?

Comment: Then how many you want and do you want this?

Comment: Hi, actually I have 5-7 controls need to be cloned in one container of course.

Comment: Then do it that way.